# Vue js:ready event not working

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

I am trying to load a simple alert in `mounted` event but its not fired

Here is my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Test</title>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.1.10/vue.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue-resource/0.1.13/vue-resource.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="app-7">

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

script

```
new Vue({
        el: '#app-7',
        data: {
            groceryList: [
                { text: 'Vegetables' },
                { text: 'Cheese' },
                { text: 'Whatever else humans are supposed to eat' }
            ],
            origin:'http://s3.myimage.com/avatar.jpg'
        },
        mounted:function () {
            console.log('ready');
            alert('ok');
        }
    })
```

Also i want to set `origin` into an `img` after the page load.
Is it possible with vue??

Comment: there is also a quotation mark more than the necessary in the "origin" declaration -> origin:'http://s3.myimage.com/avatar.jpg'

Comment: It's showing alert on mounted, http://jsbin.com/puyitan/edit?html,js,output, do you want to display an image with origin as source after mounted event?

Comment: @azs06 i want to display after DOM is loaded

Comment: @azs06 `mounted` not working in code

Comment: I will get unused property error from my IDE.

Comment: @azs06 changed my file extesion  from php to html ,now `mounted` is fired

Comment: great, it worked, for hiding image unless dom is mounted, you could set a flag and set it to `true` on mounted event. Something like this http://jsbin.com/puyitan/edit?html,js,output

Answer (score 0):

Have you rendered it to your #app-7?

For your 2nd question, yes it's possible, you can set it up like

```
<img :src="origin" />
```

Then your img will take its source from your 'origin' string.-7